# Gpa displaying and lowest grade first?

Tags: java

hello i have this question that i've been stumbling on for many days now and i will put my whole code that i tried .. 
here's the question first:
As a part-time student, you took two courses last term. Write a Java program that calculates and displays your grade point average (GPA) for the term. Your program should prompt the user to enter the grade and credit hours for each course. This information should then be displayed with the lowest grade first, and the GPA for the term should be calculated and displayed. A warning message should be printed if the GPA is less 2.0 and a congratulatory message if the GPA is 3.5 or above.

the part of displaying the lowest grade first is really confusing me

```
import java.util.*;
public class Gpa
{static Scanner stdIn= new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main (String[]args)
{
  char grade1=' ';
  char grade2=' ';
  double gradevalue1=0;
  double gradevalue2=0;
  double gpa;
  double totalpointscourse1;
  double totalpointscourse2;
  double credithours1,credithours2;
  System.out.print("enter grade for course1 like A,B,C,D,F: ");
  grade1=stdIn.next().charAt(0);
  System.out.print("enter credit hours for course1: ");
  credithours1=stdIn.nextDouble();
  System.out.print("enter grade for course2 like A,B,C,D,F: ");
  grade2=stdIn.next().charAt(0);
  System.out.print("enter credit hours for course2: ");
  credithours2=stdIn.nextDouble();

  if(grade1=='A')
     gradevalue1=4;
  else 
     if(grade1=='B')
        gradevalue1=3;
     else if (grade1=='C')
        gradevalue1=2;
     else if (grade1=='D')
        gradevalue1=1;
     else 
        gradevalue1=0;




  if(grade2=='A')
     gradevalue2=4;
  else
     if (grade2=='B')
        gradevalue2=3;
     else if (grade2=='C')
        gradevalue2=2;
     else if (grade2=='D')
        gradevalue2=1;
     else 
        gradevalue2=0;


  totalpointscourse1=gradevalue1*credithours1;
  totalpointscourse2=gradevalue2*credithours2;
  gpa= (totalpointscourse1+totalpointscourse2)/(credithours1+credithours2);

  if(grade1=='A'||grade1=='B'||grade1=='C'||grade1=='D'||grade1=='F'||grade2=='A'||grade2=='B'||
  grade2=='C'||grade2=='D'||grade2=='F')
     System.out.println(" your gpa is" + gpa);
  else
     System.out.println(" invalid gpa");


  if(gpa>=3.5)
     System.out.println("Congratulations");
  else if (gpa<2.0)
     System.out.println("WARNING");

  if (grade1>grade2) {
     System.out.println(grade2); 
     System.out.println(grade1); 

  } 
  else {
     System.out.println(grade1); 
     System.out.println(grade2); 
  }


}
}
```

and here is my output:

```
//

enter grade for course1 like A,B,C,D,F: B

enter credit hours for course1: 3

enter grade for course2 like A,B,C,D,F: A

enter credit hours for course2: 3

 your gpa is3.5
Congratulations
A
B
//
```

i'm using jGrasp btw

Answer (score 0):

You have done the job just change the loop condition from `>` to `<` and its done. But how you are getting is simple, the comparison operator actually compares the unicodes of the characters and since unicodes for alphabets are in sequence and `B` comes after `A` hence `B`'s unicode is greater than `A`'s.

Comment: i changed it as you said and B appeared before A which suggests that it's correct ,, so it's all right?? should i submit it ? thank you so much in advance

Comment: Yeah you can submit it.